# C# Generate Specific Length With-In Specific Range Unique Integer Number

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an API in .Net Core where I have to save an integer number in the SQL table. The number must be of length **'9'** any number starting from 000000001 - 9 digit number and it should never repeat in the future also I want this number at the memory level because I have to use this number for some other purposes. After doing some search, one of the most common solution is using **DateTime.Now.Ticks** and trimming its length but the problem is when concurrent HTTP requests come the ticks value might be the same.

1. One solution to solve this is by applying a **lock** on the method and releasing it when data will saved in the database but this will slow the performance of the application as the lock is expensive to use.
2. Second solution is by introducing a new table and setting the initial counter value to **1**, so on every HTTP request first apply the **UnitOfWork** read the value from the table and increment it by one and then save it and then process the other request but again there is a performance hit and not an optimum solution.

So, Is there any other solution that is faster and less expensive?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use an autoincrementing id?

Comment: Is the number supposed to be random or is sequential OK? If the latter then just use an identity or sequence in SQL Server.

Comment: Also, your two conditions seem to be at odds. You say that the number must be "of length 9". Does that means that you want to display 1 as 000000001? That's just a display issue, because numbers don't have leading zeroes. As for the range, `int.MaxValue` is 2147483647, which has 10 digits, so does that mean that the actual maximum is 999999999?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar How do we generate an auto-increment Id? if we generate at in-memory level there might a chance that it will generate the same number again in future

Comment: @user18387401 It can be random or sequential doesn't matter. I need a number before inserting it into the database, so Identity doesn't work as it gives value after insertion.

Comment: So use a sequence then.

Comment: Relational SQL databases usually offer the ability to create an autoincrementing numeric identity field. The database is responsible for generating the id, and ensure that race conditions don't occur. If you could tell us which database you're using, we could give you an even more specific answer.

Comment: @user18387401 Yes if the value is 1 then we apply '0' to make it of length '9' but the condition should be the same it will never repeat in the future.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I am using MS SQL V15.0.18390.0. I need the number at the memory level before inserting the data into the database.

Comment: Then Ovais' answer is the right one.

Comment: How many users will there be?

Comment: So, again, use a sequence, which will enable you to using an incrementing value that can be obtained independently of inserting a record. You can then format that number as a string, padding with zeroes to nine digits. That can be done in the database or in the application.

Comment: If you intend to scale out this solution (e.g. run it in a load-balanced configuration) then you *must* generate the ID in the database-- doing it in memory will cause collisions between nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a computed column/field in combination with ID(Auto increment). Auto ID will help you insert unique number and computed field will help you make that field Generate specific in length.
An example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeMaster](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [PreFix] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [EmployeeNo]  AS ([PreFix]+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(9)), 9)) PERSISTED,
  [EmployeeName] VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoInc] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Comment: I need the number at the memory level before insertion because I use that number for other purposes as well.

Comment: @Farooq If you use `INSERT tableName (columns) VALUES (values); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` then you should be able to get the freshly inserted id in the same `SqlCommand` as the insert, and then use that for the other things you need to insert. Please see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for `SCOPE_IDENTITY();`. Admittedly this will be the number without the leading zeroes, but you can fix that when you convert it to a string in C#.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar SCOPE_IDENTITY(); not handle concurrency, when execution of multiple requests goes in parallel. Also SCOPE_IDENTITY(); return the value after insertion, I need a number before insertion.

Comment: @FarooqAwan do you have a source for that claim? And why do you need it before? You would need to involve the database somehow to generate a unique 9 digit number. You can't guarantee uniqueness if you just do it in C# code. By generating the id first, you're really making life harder for yourself.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you find some way to rearrange your logic so you can insert the record first and get the ID. The identity column is made for this. Worst case scenario you can leave most fields blank and update them afterward.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I need the Id before because I have to send this as a parameter to another HTTP call in the same method so that I have to make a sync between my database and other client database based on this  Id.